# sticky navigation element behind other elements

Tags: html, navigation, positioning, sticky

I placed a sticky navigation on my page which should always be visible on front. When you scroll down on page 2 of my site you'll find out that the navigation is placed behind some other buttons.

Could someone please help me with placing it always on the front?

This is the url of page 2 of my site: `http://kmnew.kadushimarketing.com/index.php#targetAnchorPage2`

Just scroll down and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I set the z-index to 999999.